# Calling base class destructor manually together with placement new

Tags: c++, destructor, new-operator

Is it safe to call the base class destructor on a base class pointer when destructing an object which is constructed using the placement new operator?

```
#include <iostream>

class ABase
{
    public:
    virtual ~ABase()
    {
        std::cout << "~ABase()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class A : public ABase
{
    public:
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ABase* a = new (malloc(sizeof(A))) A();
    a->~ABase();
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output suggests it's ok:

```
~A()
~ABase()
```

My example on ideone.com: http://ideone.com/fzhl8x

Comment: Why wouldn't it be "safe"? How do you define "safe" anyway?

Comment: The language would be quite broken if it weren't safe. (That's more or less exactly what happens if you write `ABase* a = new A; delete a;`.)

Comment: Looks like a correct use of placement new. Some day you could replace `a->~ABase();` with [`std::destroy_at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) or write that function yourself so you don't need to repeat the type. I doubt you will get a useful answer to this question. "Looks good." is not an answer and citing all the standards clauses that proof that this is legal will be a lot of work.

Comment: Mainly this works because ~ABase() is virtual and will call the base class destructors. Someone may find the standard clauses for that